# How to authenticate with OAuth from Console Application?

Tags: authentication, oauth, automation, flickr

I want to develop simple console application for https://www.flickr.com/. It will have just few API calls for specific user account.

Flickr uses [OAuth](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html) to implement authentication.

My application users are programmers, so everyone can have own pair Api KEY and Secret.

Is there any way to use API without user intervention? Suppose, that I have **API key + Secret**, and **user + password** for flickr account.

I know, that I can parse Authorization Page for getting **oauth_verifier**. But this is not reliable.